# Regular expression to match a string outside class or function block

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-negation

Here's the reduced case of PHP code:

```php
use Package;
use Package2;

class {
    use Trait;

    function fn() {
       function() use ($var) {

       }
    }
}
```

I'd like to match only the `use` before `Package;` and `Package2;` **not** `use Trait` nor `use ($var)`

Nothing like negative lookahead and negative lookbehind seem to work. Tried this approach [Regular Expression, match characters outside curly braces { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032016/regular-expression-match-characters-outside-curly-braces)

Obviously doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/L6N4Ye/1

Using the PCRE interpreter.

Comment: Use a proper php parser. RegEx aren't suited to parse programming languages

Comment: Right, actually, no regex can help here.

Answer (score 1):

While using regex might not be the best choice here. You could use one if you have control over the format of the code you are parsing. Otherwise, using a PHP parser would be the best idea.

With that in mind, how about checking if the `use` is at the beggining of the string (`^`) ?

```
^use\s+(?![^{]*\})
```

[see here](https://regex101.com/r/L6N4Ye/2)

Comment: Saw this approach before and I was wondering if there are no edge cases other than poor code formatting?

Comment: It depends on your context, if you have access to the code, you could simply reformat it so the `use` package outside class have no space before them. If not, then you might have to use something other than regex. Cid was mentionning a php parser, which is a wonderful idea. @JakubMikita

Comment: @JakubMikita No regex will help you, see [how this solution fails](https://regex101.com/r/L6N4Ye/3)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the PHP syntax, so please forgive me for missed syntactical considerations.

Since in this particular case, you are sure that all `use`s you are interested in lie **before** the class boundary, I think what may help is to look for all `use` that is not preceded by a `{`, which can be achieved through the following regex which uses a negative lookbehind for `{`:

```
(?<!\{\s{0,100})\s*use\s*(?<pkg>.*);
```

After applying this to the entire source code, you may look for the groups named `pkg` in the matched substrings.

However, the not-so-good part in the negative lookbehind is the `\s{0,100}`, which I have included only to allow spaces after the opening brace. There must be a better way for this. I had to do this because negative lookbehinds need a calculatable maximum length, due to which `\\s*` will not work.

My assumptions on the syntax:

1. `use` is always small case
2. A `use` package statement ends with `;` necessarily
3. Whitespace is allowed freely between tokens as in the case of Java